# How to fix PSQL connection error with Docker Compose

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect my Python-Flask app with a Postgres database in a docker environment. I am using a docker-compose file to build my web and db environment.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04 as base
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev postgresql libpq-dev libffi-dev jq
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
LANG=C.UTF-8
ENV FLASK_APP=manage.py \
FLASK_ENV=development \
APP_SETTINGS=config.DevelopmentConfig \
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pw@postgres/database

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

FROM base as development
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["bash"]
```

Here is my Docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  development_default: &DEVELOPMENT_DEFAULT
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=none
      - GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=none

  web:
    <<: *DEVELOPMENT_DEFAULT
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: flask run --host=0.0.0.0

  db:
    image: postgres:10.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=db
```

Comment: I was able to resolve this. Turns out that I needed to just add a script before each call to the DB that waits until the server was connected.